# Show cytoscape qtip on right click

Tags: qtip2, cytoscape.js

I am trying to show a qtip when the user right-clicks on a node using the following code:

```
cy.on("cxttap", "node", function (evt) {
    evt.cyTarget.qtip({
        content: {
            text: "test"
        }
    });
});
```

When I right-click a node no tooltip is shown, but as soon as I left-click on the same node then the tooltip shows.

I have made sure that `cytoscape-qtip` is working and I have not added any event handlers for the `click` or `tap` events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qTip handles events itself, so you have to specify something like `cxttap` for the show event.  If you want to write your own listeners, like you have above, then your call to qtip will need a call to the qtip API to manually show.

Comment: Thanks, adding

    `show: {
        event: 'cxttap'
    }`

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set show property for right click

```
cy.elements().qtip({
                content: '<p> [SUM Outgoing call :42, THUVAPPARA</p><button id="add-to-report" class="btn btn-success">Add to report</button><br><button class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>',
                show: { event: 'cxttap' },
                position: {
                    my: 'top center',
                    at: 'bottom center'
                },
                style: {
                    classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
                    tip: {
                        width: 16,
                        height: 8
                    }
                }
            });
```